# JButton in separate class won't change JTextField(Area) text in different class

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I have a `JFrame` which contains 3 `JPanels` (each in a separate class). The first `JPanel` contains two `JTextFields` in which I write the name of the file to be read from and the condition to be fulfilled respectively. This doesn't really affect my question, so let's move on.

The second `JPanel` has a `JTextArea`.

The third `JPanel` has two `JButtons` (Load, Sort) which are supposed to load a list of entries that suffice the condition from the first `JPanel` and then reorganize them according to some rules (respectively).

### THE PROBLEM:

Ok so, the first class is the JFrame class in which i just do the standard look and feel of the window.

The second class is the first `JPanel` with two `JTextFields`.

I won't give code for this one because the second `JPanel` code is shorter and has the same problem so I imagine that the same solution would apply.

Third class contains the `JTextArea` in which I should display certain entries from the text-file.

Code:

```
public class SecondPanel extends JPanel {

    JPanel panel;
    JTextArea lista;

    public SecondPanel() {

        panel = new JPanel();
        list = new JTextArea("List");   
        list.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 150));
        this.add(list);

    }

}
```

Moving on, the fourth class contains the `Jbuttons` and the ActionListener(Button listener). Ok so here is the part of the code from the button listener class
CODE:

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    SecondPanel secondPanel = new SecondPanel();
    FirstPanel firstPanel = new FirstPanel();
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Load")) {
            //calls method that loads data from the text in a firstPanel field
            loadData(firstPanel.theFile.getText());
            for(int i = 0; i< students.length; i++) {

                if(students[i]!=null) {
                    // doesn't write anything tried with .setText etc.
                    secondPanel.list.append(students[i]+"\n");

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

So the program won't get text  when i type in the `JTextField` designated for the file path. And when i do it manually in the code, It won't write the changes to the list on the Window (JTextArea). But when i `System.out.print` to the console it prints the changes and lists entries correctly as well as any `setText` changes I make. It just won't write or read to and from the Window..

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling your setText methods on the wrong objects.
In your listener class, you declared two new panels as class variables, and then you call your methods on them, but i think those panels are not the ones you really want to change.

You should first add your panels to your Jframe object, and refer to them on your ActionListener.

Here i provide you a minimal code which modifies a JTextArea when a JButton is pressed. (same for a JTextField)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {
    SecondPanel sPanel;

    public MyJFrame() {
        super("main");

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("load");
        button.addActionListener(new LoadListener());

        c.add(sPanel = new SecondPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class SecondPanel extends JPanel {
        public JTextArea list;

        public SecondPanel() {
            super();
            list = new JTextArea("List");
            list.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 150));
            add(list);
        }
    }

    class LoadListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            sPanel.list.setText("new text for the jtext area");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyJFrame();
    }
}
```